# Diagram with crossing arrows

Tags: diagrams, arrows

My problem is that I have crossing lines/arrows in my diagram and during my search, I just found answers like [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/line-junction/) which do not suit for my problem. Maybe someone can help me out with this. The arrow from the Firms to the Government has to cross the arrows between the CB and the Banks but in such a way that one can read the text. Is it possible to put the arrow on different layers or something?

```
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth',
    %Define style for boxes
    punkt/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=3.5em,
           text centered}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto, description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]

 %nodes
 \node[punkt]                      (Banks)  {Banks ($B_b$)};
 \node[left=4cm of Banks]          (dummy1) {};
 \node[right=4cm of Banks]         (dummy2) {};
 \node[punkt, above=4cm of dummy1] (CB)     {CB};
 \node[punkt, below=4cm of dummy1] (Gov)    {Government};
 \node[punkt, above=4cm of dummy2] (Firms)  {Firms ($F_f$)};
 \node[punkt, below=4cm of dummy2] (HH)     {HH ($HH_{hh}$)};


\path[->, >=latex, thick]
  (Gov.20)      edge[] node[below, rotate=48]  {\small Bonds}                       (Banks.220)
  (Banks.200)   edge[] node[above, rotate=48]  {\small Deposits}                    (Gov.40)
  (Firms.250)   edge[] node[above, rotate=90]  {\small wage, dividends}             (HH.110)
  (HH.70)       edge[] node[below, rotate=90]  {\small equity, consumption}         (Firms.290)
  (Gov.350)     edge[] node[below]             {\small unempl. benefit}             (HH.190)
  (HH.170)      edge[] node[above]             {\small Taxes}                       (Gov.10)
  (CB.325)      edge[] node[below, rotate=-50] {\small interest, OSDF}              (Banks.160)
  (Banks.143)   edge[] node[above, rotate=-50] {\small interest, IDL, OMO, OSLF}    (CB.345)
  (Firms.200)   edge[] node[above, rotate=48]  {\small principal/interest payments} (Banks.40)
  (Banks.20)    edge[] node[below, rotate=48]  {\small Loans, interest}             (Firms.220)
  (HH.143)      edge[] node[above, rotate=-50]  {\small equity}                     (Banks.345)
  (Banks.325)   edge[] node[below, rotate=-50]  {\small interest, dividends}        (HH.160)
  (Banks.west)  edge[out=200, in=340, looseness=5] node[below]  {\small interbank loans} (Banks.east)
  (Firms.170)   edge[bend right=35]                node[above, near end, rotate=60]  {\small Taxes}               (Gov.120);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a friend of simple solutions: (1) draw the crossing edge, (2) draw a semi-transparent white rectangle to fade it in the background, (3) draw other stuff on top of it.

```
\path[->, >=latex, thick](Firms.170)   edge[bend right=35]   node[above, near end, rotate=60]  {\small Taxes}               (Gov.120);

\path[fill=white, opacity=0.8] (-3.2,1) rectangle +(1.5,2);

\path[->, >=latex, thick]
  (Gov.20)      edge[] node[below, rotate=48]  {\small Bonds}                            (Banks.220)
[...]
  (Banks.west)  edge[out=200, in=340, looseness=5] node[below]  {\small interbank loans} (Banks.east);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach using the `background` layer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}     %new code
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth,
    %Define style for boxes
    punkt/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=3.5em,
           text centered}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto, description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]

 %nodes
 \node[punkt]                      (Banks)  {Banks ($B_b$)};
 \node[left=4cm of Banks]          (dummy1) {};
 \node[right=4cm of Banks]         (dummy2) {};
 \node[punkt, above=4cm of dummy1] (CB)     {CB};
 \node[punkt, below=4cm of dummy1] (Gov)    {Government};
 \node[punkt, above=4cm of dummy2] (Firms)  {Firms ($F_f$)};
 \node[punkt, below=4cm of dummy2] (HH)     {HH ($HH_{hh}$)};


\path[->, >=latex, thick]
  (Gov.20)      edge[] node[below, rotate=48]  {\small Bonds}                       (Banks.220)
  (Banks.200)   edge[] node[above, rotate=48]  {\small Deposits}                    (Gov.40)
  (Firms.250)   edge[] node[above, rotate=90]  {\small wage, dividends}             (HH.110)
  (HH.70)       edge[] node[below, rotate=90]  {\small equity, consumption}         (Firms.290)
  (Gov.350)     edge[] node[below]             {\small unempl. benefit}             (HH.190)
  (HH.170)      edge[] node[above]             {\small Taxes}                       (Gov.10)
  (CB.325)      edge[] node[fill=white,below, sloped] {\small interest, OSDF}              (Banks.160)     %new code
  (Banks.143)   edge[] node[fill=white,above, sloped] {\small interest, IDL, OMO, OSLF}    (CB.345)        %new code
  (Firms.200)   edge[] node[above, rotate=48]  {\small principal/interest payments} (Banks.40)
  (Banks.20)    edge[] node[below, rotate=48]  {\small Loans, interest}             (Firms.220)
  (HH.143)      edge[] node[above, rotate=-50]  {\small equity}                     (Banks.345)
  (Banks.325)   edge[] node[below, rotate=-50]  {\small interest, dividends}        (HH.160)
  (Banks.west)  edge[out=200, in=340, looseness=5] node[below]  {\small interbank loans} (Banks.east);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]   %new code
   \path[->, >=latex, thick]  (Firms.170)   edge[bend right=35]                node[above, near end, rotate=60]  {\small Taxes}               (Gov.120);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The scoped path goes behind the main path

Comment: The answer of Harald was what I was searching for, but thanks also for yours since I'm gonna need this in a another diagram. Is there a possibility to define more than one (background) layer?

Comment: for multiple layers see section 109 of the TikZ manual, the macros you are looking for are `\pgfdeclarelayer{>name>}`, `\pgfsetlayer{>name>}`, etc.