# How to obtain a custom arrow tip in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I wonder if it is possible to obtain **exactly** the following arrow tip with `TikZ-PGF`? I have searched all possible solutions in the PGF manual and in this site but only near ones are available. Here are some snapshots at different sizes and orientations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The picture in the middle provides the most accurate shape.

I need the details. There are **eight** points that make up the convex hull of the arrow tip in my case in contrast to only four points in, e.g., `stealth` or three points in `latex`.

Here are the details needed (sure I exaggerate a bit to highlight the small details):

[image]

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Starting on page 1021 is a description of how to create your own arrow shape using \pgfdeclarearrow.  So it is possible.

Comment: What is the specification for being **exactly** the same?

Comment: That is to closely imitate the middle picture. You see if one smoothes the upper and lower envelopes it becomes like `latex'` and the base is more like `stealth` (pay attention to the ends of the base, they are beveled). I don't need these approximations as these tiny `glyphs` are the most beautiful attributes of it especially when printed on low resolution printers.

Comment: You say to 'pay attention' to details and then say that you 'don't need these approximations'. Which approximations?

Comment: I explained in the updated post.

Comment: What you have is a double arrow. One is a thin arrow superimposed on a stealth arrow. What I asked is how much it should stick out or how much is the inset etc. If you look at the pgf manual you can see how to combine two arrow tips. Then you can define what you want and we can create the arrow tip quickly. But we need those numbers.

Comment: Any reasonable values can be OK to start with. After this we can fine tune these to the desired shape. But if you use `stealth` for the base you will join points 2,3 and 7,8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve this. That was easy after I found the code for the built in `stealth` arrow tip. The idea is to, simply, add the extra points in my case which are points 3,4,6, and 7 to the original code for `stealth`. After adding the required points, some more tuning was required to get the desired shape as I was looking for.

Now here is the code I built for this:

```
\pgfarrowsdeclare{varstealth}{varstealth}
 {
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-5.59\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{4.5\pgflinewidth}}
 {
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4.5\pgflinewidth}{0pt}} %Point5
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.63\pgflinewidth}{1.09\pgflinewidth}} %Point4
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.48\pgflinewidth}{3.06\pgflinewidth}} %Point3
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.59\pgflinewidth}{3.0\pgflinewidth}}%Point2
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-3.95\pgflinewidth}{0pt}} %Point1
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.59\pgflinewidth}{-3.0\pgflinewidth}}%Point8
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.48\pgflinewidth}{-3.06\pgflinewidth}}%Point7
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.63\pgflinewidth}{-1.09\pgflinewidth}}%Point6
  \pgfusepathqfill
 }
```

I have also experimented using it as in the following example (originally found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202511/diagram-with-crossing-arrows)):

[image]

And here is the code also for this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
\begin{document}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{varstealth}{varstealth}% My new arrow tip declaration
 {
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-5.58\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{4.5\pgflinewidth}}
 {
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4.5\pgflinewidth}{0pt}} %Point5
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.63\pgflinewidth}{1.09\pgflinewidth}} %Point4
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.48\pgflinewidth}{3.06\pgflinewidth}} %Point3
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.59\pgflinewidth}{3.0\pgflinewidth}}%Point2
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-3.95\pgflinewidth}{0pt}} %Point1
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.59\pgflinewidth}{-3.0\pgflinewidth}}%Point8
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5.48\pgflinewidth}{-3.06\pgflinewidth}}%Point7
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.63\pgflinewidth}{-1.09\pgflinewidth}}%Point6
  \pgfusepathqfill
 }

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=varstealth,line width= 1pt,node distance=1cm, auto, description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt},punkt/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, very thick,text width=6.5em,minimum height=3.5em,text centered}]

 %nodes
 \node[punkt]                      (Banks)  {Banks ($B_b$)};
 \node[left=4cm of Banks]          (dummy1) {};
 \node[right=4cm of Banks]         (dummy2) {};
 \node[punkt, above=4cm of dummy1] (CB)     {CB};
 \node[punkt, below=4cm of dummy1] (Gov)    {Government};
 \node[punkt, above=4cm of dummy2] (Firms)  {Firms ($F_f$)};
 \node[punkt, below=4cm of dummy2] (HH)     {HH ($HH_{hh}$)};

\path[->]
  (Gov.20)      edge[] node[below, rotate=48]  {\small Bonds}                       (Banks.220)
  (Banks.200)   edge[] node[above, rotate=48]  {\small Deposits}                    (Gov.40)
  (Firms.250)   edge[] node[above, rotate=90]  {\small wage, dividends}             (HH.110)
  (HH.70)       edge[] node[below, rotate=90]  {\small equity, consumption}         (Firms.290)
  (Gov.350)     edge[] node[below]             {\small unempl. benefit}             (HH.190)
  (HH.170)      edge[] node[above]             {\small Taxes}                       (Gov.10)
  (CB.325)      edge[] node[fill=white,below, sloped] {\small interest, OSDF}              (Banks.160)     
  (Banks.143)   edge[] node[fill=white,above, sloped] {\small interest, IDL, OMO, OSLF}    (CB.345)        
  (Firms.200)   edge[] node[above, rotate=48]  {\small principal/interest payments} (Banks.40)
  (Banks.20)    edge[] node[below, rotate=48]  {\small Loans, interest}             (Firms.220)
  (HH.143)      edge[] node[above, rotate=-50] {\small equity}                     (Banks.345)
  (Banks.325)   edge[] node[below, rotate=-50] {\small interest, dividends}        (HH.160)
  (Banks.west)  edge[out=200, in=340, looseness=5] node[below]  {\small interbank loans} (Banks.east);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]   %new code
\path[->, thick](Firms.170) edge[bend right=35]node[above, near end, rotate=60]  {\small Taxes} (Gov.120);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```