# highlight object using brushed stroke

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

[image: highlight object using brushed stroke]

I would like to reproduce these object conforming brushed strokes to highlight.
I saw these at:

http://brickisland.net/DDGSpring2020/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DDG_458_SP19_Lecture04_kForms.pdf

These highlights also include a single right cancel and left cancel, and could be placed and fit/conform around/on on any size object.

here is another example of use: [image: enter manifold]

p.s. I have now communicated with the author, and was kind to explain that the slides were created in Apple's Keynote software, though a similar effect could be achieved via PowerPoint.  Specifically, the equations were typeset in the application called LaTeXiT, and copy/paste them into Keynote.  The crosses and circles are then drawn using built-in shapes in Keynote.

It may be possible get a similar effect in LaTeX/Beamer without too much effort?   One route is to use TikZ to get the brush stroke effect? Another is to use the `overpic' package to take an external image of the brush strokes and place them over the text.  Here likely need to use a PNG file, so that part of the image can be made transparent.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320033/134144 could be interesting

Comment: based on 134144, using a tikz \node with an \includegraphics transparent image over an equation might do the trick.